# delete vector inside vector issue

Tags: c++, vector

```
template <typename T>
class dvec {
    size_t n = 0;
    size_t capacity = 0;
    T* data = nullptr;
public:
    dvec() {
        recapacity(21);
    }
    virtual ~dvec() {
        if (data != nullptr) {
            delete[] data;
            data = nullptr;
        }
    }
    T& operator [] (size_t k) {
        if (k < n)
            return data[k];
        throw "Index out of range";
    }
    void recapacity(size_t k = capacity) {
        capacity = k;
        const size_t bytes = sizeof(T) * capacity;
        T* newData = static_cast<T*>(::operator new(bytes));
        memcpy(newData, data, sizeof(T) * n);
        if (data != nullptr)
            delete[] data;
        data = newData;
    }
    void resize(size_t k, T init = T()) {
        if (k > capacity)
            recapacity(2 * k);
        for (size_t i = n; i < k; i++)
            data[i] = init;
        n = k;
    }
    void push_back(const T& a) {
        resize(n + 1);
        data[n - 1] = a;
    }
};
```

I want to make some custom vector but current my vector doesn't work in vector scoped vector.
This throw error when delete (going out scorp)
I guess first inside vector delete so outside vector can't delete spaces that have been deleted.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but your class handle dynamic allocation in its default constructor and destructor. According to the [rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/3545273) or [Five](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4782757/3545273) it should have non default copy (move?) constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: The `memcpy` means you can't handle just any T. You'll need a concept check: `template <std::is_trivial_v T>`. And this will (correctly) block a vector of vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation of `recapacity` is faulty.

First problem is that `memcpy` requires trivially copyable types, which `dvec<T>` isn't, so `dvec<dvec<T>>` is ill-formed.

Second problem is that you use `::operator new` to allocate, and `delete[]` to deallocate, so `dvec<T>` is ill-formed.

Third problem is that you can't have a data member as the default for a parameter, so `size_t k = capacity` probably isn't what you think it is

Forth problem is that you lack copy/move constructors/assignments, so it is easy to have leaks or double deletion.

```
dvec(const dvec &other) : n(other.n) {
    recapacity(other.n);
    std::copy_n(data, n, other.data);
}
dvec(dvec &&other) 
: n(std::exchange(other.n, 0)),
  capacity(std::exchange(other.capacity, 0)),
  data(std::exchange(other.data, nullptr)) {
}
dvec& operator=(const dvec& other) {
    if (capacity < other.n) {
        recapacity(other.n);
    }
    std::copy_n(data, n, other.data);
    return *this;
}
dvec& operator=(dvec&& other) {
    n = std::exchange(other.n, 0);
    capacity = std::exchange(other.capacity, 0);
    data = std::exchange(other.data, nullptr);
    return *this;
}
virtual /*?*/ ~dvec() {
    ::operator delete(static_cast<void*>(data));
}
void recapacity(size_t k) {
    capacity = k;
    T* newData = static_cast<T*>(::operator new(sizeof(T) * capacity));
    if constexpr (std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T>) {
        std::uninitialised_move_n(data, size, newData);
    } else {
        std::uninitialised_copy_n(data, size, newData);
        std::destroy_n(data, size);
    }
    ::operator delete(static_cast<void*>(data));
    data = newData;
}
```